# Parcitular website cannot be read via requests.get() method

Tags: python-3.x, get, request

I have the following code:

```
import requests

url1 = 'https://www.google.com/'
url2 ='https://gaz.tge.pl/pl/rdn/tgebase/?date=2017-01-01/'

response1 = requests.get(url1)
response2 = requests.get(url2)
```

First response is accomplished, but the second one is not. It seems it depends on website type. Could somebody explain me the difference between those two? Why the second one is not working?

Thanks for any clue or advice.

Comment: Works fine for me? >>> import requests
>>> url2 ='https://gaz.tge.pl/pl/rdn/tgebase/?date=2017-01-01/'
>>> rv = requests.get(url2)
>>> rv
<Response [200]>
>>> rv.text
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"\n .....

Comment: Thanks. That's strange, when I switched to another virualenv everything was fine. It seems I have an issue with my environment.

Comment: np, glad you got it working